# EF 4.0 LINQ one to many / many to one

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-one, one-to-many

Just starting to use LINQ as well as EF.

I have a set of tables in the following configuration:

PublicUtility (UtilityCode) * ----> 1 (UtilityCode) Utility (UtilityCode) 1 -----> * (UtilityCode) UtilityDetail

I have a query in SQL.  Based on some other business rules this query will either return 1 value or NULL.

SELECT
@UtilityCode = UtilityDetail.UtilityCode
FROM
UtilityDetail
INNER JOIN PublicUtility ON
    PublicUtility.SubdivisionCode = @SubdivisionCode AND
    PublicUtility.Year = @PublicUtilityYear AND
    PublicUtility.UtilityCode = UtilityDetail.UtilityCode
WHERE
UtilityDetail.DebtPurposeCode = @DebtPurposeCode

How could I rewrite this using LINQ to entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using (YourObjectContext ctx = new YourObjectContext())
{
    var code = (from ud in ctx.UtilityDetails
                join pu in PublicUtility on ud.UtilityCode equals pu.UtilityCode
                where ud.DeptPurposeCode == [code_value] && pu.SubdivisionCode == [subdivcode_value] && pu.Year == [year_value]
                select new {ud.UtilityCode}).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was driving my crazy.  I was trying to reference the UtilityDetails from the PublicUtility.Utility.UtilityDetails and wasn't getting anywhere.  I'm having trouble not thinking in T-SQL...